# Update Query with Join (MYSQL) taking hours

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a query (tried it locally and on my server) the query is an update query where it takes values from one table and puts the value in the second table where the ISBN field is the same so what I have is

```
update valorebest2 
join buylist on valorebest2.isbn= buylist.isbn
set valorebest2.binding = buylist.binding, valorebest2.buy = buylist.buy
```

`valorebest2` has 400,000 records, and `buylist` has about 300,00 (will have about 1,000,000 when completed). To run this update takes 6-8 hours.

Is there a different way to do this that is quicker? I can use PHP or Ajax if required.

Comment: do you have an index on both join fields?

Comment: I can't be sure of your data requirements and usage, but could it be easier to just drop the updated fields from `valorebest2` and just JOIN to `buylist` when those values are needed? Also, what @steven said; and what data type is `isbn`?

Comment: isbn numbers are kind of varchar.

Comment: and please tell us what engine you are using. i suspect it is innodb. correct?

Comment: I have an index on valorebest2 called id (i had one on both tables but dropped it out of buylist hoping it would speed it up---no difference). i need to have two independent tables with the data because they are updated at different times and its not taking all of the data from buylist. and yes steven is correct isbn is varchar, buy is double and binding is var. No using MyISAM. (cant change that)

Comment: you need one index on valorebest2.isbn and one index on buylist.isbn to boost up the join.

Comment: removing an index will never speed up anything but writing the index field.

Comment: you might consider migrating this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @steven re:varchar, I figured it would be character type; but `TEXT` would've been horrible, and since ISBN are of a fixed length (mostly) `CHAR` (instead of `VARCHAR`) _may_ help with performance under MyISAM if the change results in a table having fixed length rows.

Comment: please post the EXPLAIN of your SELECT to see the reason of your problem. If possible you can also post a SHOW CREATE TABLE from both

Comment: Modify question expression.

Comment: I have posted the answer that worked thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through everyone's suggestion i changed the table so that it converted the isbn column to double instead of varchar and i index the isbn field in both tables. it reduced the time to 37 seconds.